# How to cancel double-tap scroll gesture on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

I'm doing a mobile web project now, which has a page with a fixed footer.

To let 300ms tap delay go away, I have already add meta tag in the header tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in Safari,  double-tap is a scroll gesture which makes the fixed footer move up a little bit.

How can I cancel this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```